# How can I return a value from function with multiple nested functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, closures, nested-function

The problem: I want to call a value from a nested method outside of its parent method. In other words, I want the output from "console.log(someObjects[i].valueChecker);" to be either "true" or "false." However, it is just returning the function itself.

What I've done so far: So I have been scouring the web/stack overflow for a solution, but either I haven't found a solution, or I just can't make sense of it. I think it has something to do with "closures," and most of the solutions to problems I've seen have been to return from the submethod, and then return the submethod from the parent method. However, every time I've tried this, I've just encountered numerous errors-- either another submethod suddenly doesn't exist, or the code runs, but the output is still a function. I wonder if having multiple methods affects the issue.

Context: I'm making a platformer game, and there are multiple types of the same enemy. I want to check for collision between the player and weapon and thusly need some values from the enemy function (I don't want to use the word "class," but I'm not sure about the appropriate terminology). I'm much more familiar with Java though, so it is frustrating me to not be able to create a separate class and just have a method to give me values back.

```js
//assume all the other html/main stuff is already set up
var temp = {
  create: c4,
  update: u4
}
MyObject = function(value) {
  this.value = value; //passed in value
  var magicNumber = 4; //local value initialized/declared

  this.valueChecker = function() {
    //return boolean
    return this.value == this.magicNumber;
  }

  this.otherValueChecker = function() {
    //return boolean
    return (this.value + 1) == this.magicNumber;
  }
}

//just make the space bar tied to a boolean
var someKeyPress;

function c4() {
  someKeyPress = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.A);
}

var someObjects = [];
//... later on in the program, presuming key already coded
function u4() {
  //add a new MyObject to array someObjects
  if (someKeyPress.isDown) {
    //check with various random numbers between 3 to 5
    someObjects.push(new MyObject(game.rnd.integerInRange(3, 5)));
  }

  //run through MyObject(s) added to someObjects, and see if any match number
  for (var i = 0; i < someObjects.length; i++) {
    console.log(someObjects[i].valueChecker);
  }
}



/* current output
    ƒ () {
        //return boolean
  return this.value == this.magicNumber;
 }
    */
```

Comment: I haven't read the code in detail - but will it not work if you log the actual return value of the function, rather than the function itself. That is, do `console.log(someObjects[i].valueChecker())`?

Comment: You will have to actually *call* the method using `()` to call it and get its result... No, this hardly has anything do with closures

Comment: First off, many thanks for the comments. After editing the code to call the method console.log(someObjects[i].valueChecker()) and make the statement always true though (aka MagicNumber and this.value always equal 4), it appears to always print false regardless.

Comment: That `var magicNumber = 4` declares a local variable that is never used. You either need to change it to `this.magicNumber = 4` or change your valueChecker methods to check against `magicNumber`

Comment: @Robin Zigmond That did it. Thank you very much! Apparently, it was a real simple fix all along and my newbish-ness in javascript was the real problem. I need to go refresh on local/global variables

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
console.log(someObjects[i].valueChecker())
```

Because I see the value checker as a function

```
this.valueChecker = function()
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. However, after doing that, it appears to give now always false. This is also after making magicnumber and this.value set to 4. Granted, that could be a problem somewhere else with my logic, but I at least can't see it.